How to disable 'RMB cancels the orbit operation'?
When you orbit in the Viewport (ex, hold MMB and drag), the orbiting is undone if you click RMB. This is in Blender docs: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html
However, when I use a pen and drawing tablet, this sometimes undoes an orbit that I wanted to do. How do I disable the RMB cancelling?
For my pen, I have the rocker button on it set to lower rock is MMB, and upper rock is RMB. This is convenient for most things, but undoing the orbit is really frustrating. I orbit something in sculpt mode, get it to just the right angle, let go of the pen button -- and bam!! It snaps back to before the orbit. I guess what happens is that when I let go of the lower rocker, I'm still pressing the top rocker, which triggers the RMB - cancel orbit.

In the Preferences > Keymap, set the search to Key-Binding, search for MMB.
Under 3D View > Rotate View > View3D Rotate Modal, uncheck the Cancel entry.

For some reason it likes to fold the Rotate View when you do that, but if you open it again you should see the Cancel entry unckecked.
Then if you don't have preferences autosave enabled, use the bottom-left hamburger menu to manually save your preferences:


I think that was it, doesn't happen anymore. Sir, you have my endless thanks and appreciation -- that was so frustrating and painful!
